# Find the optimal value from a Residual function

Tags: python, function, minimize, minimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have two functions,

```
f(x), f(x,a)
```

I can plot `x-f(x)` and `x-f(x,a)` for a family of `a` values.

Now I want to know for which value of `a` does the residual becomes minimum, that `f(x)~f(x,a)` for `a` will be minimum.
Both `f(x)` and `f(x,a)` returns an array for an input of `x` array.

I tried [scipy minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) function, but I am getting lot of errors (although i think they are different errors
(`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`).

But I would like to know, how to obtain the minimum value of `b` in python ? Is there any tailored function for this ?

Here is an example of what I have tried:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def f1(x):
    a = x + 2
    return (a)
def f2(x, b):
    a = x**3 + b
    return (a)
def res2(x, b):
    return (f1(x) - f2(x, b))

x = np.linspace(2, 5, 4)
cc = 20
print(res2(x, cc))  
minimize(res2, x, method='BFGS', jac=rosen_der)
```

But this is not working.